# Java applet doesn't fully garbage collect on close

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a java applet that loads up a scroll view that you can add several thousand views to, everything works fine.  If I close that browser window and open a new window and view my applet again and start adding views it eventually runs out of memory.  It seems like garbage collection didn't occur when I closed the window before:

a: why isn't memory freed once I close the window?

b: how can I make sure it is freed?

This is the latest version of java with FF and Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the code, my guess would be a reference to the window or one of it's components in your code which keeps it reachable.

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately depending on how you look at it) I was accidentally keeping a strong reference to all the objects in question and I didn't notice because I thought it was commented out :p

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the Java Browser Plugin can launch the applets in the same JVM. There is a applet parameter that you can use to launch your applet in a seperate JVM every time its launched in a new window:

```
<param name="separate_jvm" value="true">
```

Also you could leverage the `start()`, `stop()` and `destroy()` methods of you applet to clean up resources you are using.

There are some interesting facts about the java plugin. Check the [forum](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5405876). It has some important links

Comment: separate_jvm is an interesting param, for whatever reason though it's not launching a new jvm for me (even w/the latest Java).  I put some code in stop() to remove stuff from the Swing GUI on exit but its still not GCing.  It kind of bottles my mind that after I exit the application it keeps stuff in the VM's memory, makes no sense.